# Ovveride, the paintevent of the Qwidget

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to put a background image in mt QWidget, can anyone help me on
this.

how to Ovveride, the paintevent of the Qwidget and draw a image there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QWidget widget(0);
    widget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(1.PNG)");

    QGridLayout *leftLayout = new QGridLayout();
    leftLayout->setSpacing (0);

    widget.setLayout(leftLayout);  

    widget.show(); 
    return app.exec();
}
```

Where **1.PNG** is the image located in the same directory with the app.

Comment: Is there any other way that doesn't involve CSS (ideally one that uses embedded resources?)

Comment: (I'd submit my own question, but submitting similar questions is frowned upon)

Comment: @advs89 I guess you are talking about qrc file... So it's not a problem: *widget.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/1.PNG)");*, where *:/images/1.PNG* is a embedded resource file. After that you only have to add information about 1.PNG to the res.qrc file...